# Water in door columns

Tags: pontiac, g6, recall

I am getting water in both doors columns. After rain, both of my seatbelts are wet. In cold weather, they freeze in place. I have read many similar complaints. Is anyone aware of a recall for this issue? This is an 08 Pontiac G6 Street Edition. I am aware it is an issue with the drain hoses from the sunroof.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you made sure that those drain hoses are clear?